# How can I list all users that are part of same teams as current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a messaging site where any user can send messages to each other, but now is there a way to only show users that are in the same teams as the current user?

My user.rb model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

end
```

My team.rb model:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

My membership.rb model:

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

My "Contacts" view:

```
<li>
  <% @user = User.find(current_user.id) %>
  <% @all_teams = @user.teams %>

  <% @all_teams.users.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.name %> 
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by joining the memberships table and applying a where clause to the join table:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships

  def users_with_same_groups
    User.joins(:memberships)
        .where(memberships: { group: self.groups })
        .where.not(id: self.id)
  end
end
```

SQL:

```
SELECT "users".*
FROM   "users"
       INNER JOIN "memberships"
               ON "memberships"."user_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE  "memberships"."group_id" IN (SELECT "groups"."id"
                                    FROM   "groups"
                                           INNER JOIN "memberships"
                                                   ON "groups"."id" =
                                                      "memberships"."group_id"
                                    WHERE  "memberships"."user_id" = $1)
LIMIT  $2
```

Since it produces an inner join only records with a match in joined table will be included. Meaning that result set will only include users with at least one group in common.

`.where.not(id: self.id)` excludes *self* from the results.

Comment: Thanks for the help, how would I go about displaying this in my contacts view?

Comment: It returns an ActiveRecord::Relation that you can iterate through just like any other collection. I think you can figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the logic outside of your views, and instead put it in a controller (or, as @max suggests, in the User model):

```
#current_user_controller.rb

class CurrentUserController < ApplicationController    
  def contacts
    @contacts = User.joins(:groups)
                    .where(groups: {id: current_user.groups})
                    .where.not(id: current_user).uniq
  end
end
```

Now you can iterate over `@contacts` in your `current_user/contacts` view.